# Extracting certain fields for selected feature from point shapefile file with multiple features using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a point shapefile that is filled with many features.

If I have 1 feature selected I need to be able to export certain fields of that selected feature (ID, lat, long) into a dbf file.

What tools in ModelBuilder can accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you plan to do this repeatedly, I would suggest creating a model that would allow you to 1) pick your input layer, 2) write a query to select the features you want, and 3) define the fields you want (and rename if needed) and 4) copy the query features to a new output layer.  You can do this using just 2 commands: "Make Feature Layer" and "Copy Features".  Then make sure to "Make Parameters" for each of the 3 items you want to control from the model.  Then you can run it just like a built-in tool with a user interface.

[image]

Above is the way the model would likely look (note the "P" for exposed parameters), and below is the UI that is automatically generated for you (no scripting or programming needed) after exposing the right parameters. Note that you can choose any input file name (layer), define a search query, check on/off the fields that you want to keep, rename fields if necessary, and define the new file name.

[image]

Comment: You sir are awesome, thank you for this and here is your internet high five!

*high five*

Comment: After re-reading the post, I realize I forgot about the "export to DBF".  As Zachary pointed out, simply replace "Create Features" in my model with "Copy Rows" and you can export directly to DBF.  Or if you want both features and a standalone DBF, you can link both a Copy Rows and a Copy Features command from the "Output Layer" in the model.

Comment: How can I change it so it does not add the table in the "list by source" window?  It takes forever to load so if I stopped it from adding it in that window it will cut down the time it takes for this model to process greatly.

Answer (score 7):

[Feature Class to Feature Class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000020000000.htm) lets you selectively include some but not all fields:

Converts a shapefile, coverage feature class, or geodatabase feature class to a shapefile or geodatabase feature class.

> Usage
>
> - The Field Map parameter controls how the input fields in the Input Features will be written to the Output Features.
>
>   - To drop fields during the conversion, delete input fields from the Field Map. This will not affect the input feature class.

Comment: Yes, an excellent solution.  You would then just export the attribute table to a dbf from ArcMap.

Comment: How can I specify which feature in the shapefile to run this on?

Comment: All GP tools should only ever act on the selection set of a layer.

Answer (score 0):

The Delete Field tool will let you delete selected fields from an input layer, and the Create Table tool will export a layer to a dbf file.  Both of these can be added to a model.